# Dual of finite dimensional Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

The dual space H* is the space of all continuous linear functions from the space H into the base field. It carries a natural norm, defined by
$$\|\varphi\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1, x\in H} |\varphi(x)|.$$
The dual space is also an inner product space and it is also complete, so it is a Hilbert space in its own right. But, usually, I read this definition for infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Is this definition still valid for finite dimensional Hilbert space? I think that the answer should be "yes", because a finite dimensional Hilbert space should be a subspace of an infinite dimensional space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's also valid in the finite-dimensional case. Note that then the continuity requirement is redundant, every linear function whose domain is a finite-dimensional normed space is continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Thank you very much! :)